# Python - Pass UniqueIntList datatype as parameter while calling procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, pyodbc

I need to execute a procedure from Python as shown here:

```
DECLARE @LayoutID INT = 9,
        @PrivateFL INT = 0,
        @FromDate DATETIME = '20100101',
        @ToDate DATETIME = '20211001',
        @VesselIDs dbo.UniqueIntList

INSERT INTO @VesselIDs 
VALUES (202), (330)

EXEC usp_GetComments @LayoutID, @PrivateFL, @FromDate, @ToDate, @VesselIDs
```

How do I pass `@VesselIDs` as a parameter while executing it using Python?

I tried this code, but it's not working

```
list = [202,330]

storedProc = "EXEC usp_GetComments @LayoutID=?, @PrivateFL=?, @FromDate=?, @ToDate=?, @VesselIDs=?"

params = (9,0,'20100101','20211001',list)
```

Answer (score 2):

Do as below:

```
storedProc = "EXEC usp_GetComments @LayoutID=?, @PrivateFL=?, @FromDate=?, @ToDate=?, @VesselIDs=?"


fktvp = [(202,),(330,)]
fkparams = (9,0,'20100101','20211001',fktvp)
 

cursor.execute( storedProc, fkparams )
```